# PayPal Parallel Payments for multiple orders

Tags: magento, paypal

I checked the [PayPal Developer Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) to find a suitable solution for my payment handling requirement. Now I'm not sure if parallel payments can be used as I need it.

Scenario:
The customer in the shop can have multiple carts, because each cart is associated with a selectable delivery time. On checkout, every cart has to become a separate order with its own invoice. Now, when paying with PayPal, every order needs to have its own payment with transaction ID, etc. 
In summary, I don't need payments to multiple receivers in one go, but multiple payments for each order to one receiver.

Is this even possible?

Additional info:
Using Magento and the build in PayPal Payment module. But I could extend it to handle split payments.

If I didn't make myself clear, please just ask and I try to clarify.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Parallel payments would be for splitting up the payment between multiple receivers.  That's not what you want.

You would need to build a custom extension for Magento that runs 2 separate transactions with a single checkout.

With a credit card checkout you could simply make the call to process the credit card twice on the same order and display everything accordingly to the user.  That would be pretty simple.

For PayPal payments you would need to use Express Checkout and setup a billing agreement so that you can run reference transactions.  Then you would run through the checkout and process the first payment like usual with Express Checkout, but then also tie in a call to process the reference transaction for the additional order.

So yes, it's possible.  Just going to take some custom development.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, for your response. In the meantime, I checked with PayPal Dev Support and they explained the API to me, difference between orders and authorizations. Combined with your input, I should be able to find a solution. Thanks again!